# How can I return a copy of a vector containing elements not in a set?

Tags: c++, stl, c++11

Suppose I have the following two data structures:

```
std::vector<int> all_items;
std::set<int> bad_items;
```

The `all_items` vector contains all known items and the `bad_items` vector contains a list of bad items. These two data structures are populated entirely independent of one another.

What's the proper way to write a method that will return a `std::vector<int>` contain all elements of `all_items` not in `bad_items`?

Currently, I have a clunky solution that I think can be done more concisely. My understanding of STL function adapters is lacking. Hence the question. My current solution is:

```
struct is_item_bad {
    std::set<int> const* bad_items;
    bool operator() (int const i) const {
        return bad_items.count(i) > 0;
    }
};

std::vector<int> items() const {
    is_item_bad iib = { &bad_items; };
    std::vector<int> good_items(all_items.size());
    std::remove_copy_if(all_items.begin(),  all_items.end(), 
                        good_items.begin(), is_item_bad);
    return good_items; 
}
```

Assume `all_items`, `bad_items`, `is_item_bad` and `items()` are all a part of some containing class. Is there a way to write them `items()` getter such that:

- It doesn't need temporary variables in the method?
- It doesn't need the custom functor, `struct is_item_bad`?

I had hoped to just use the `count` method on `std::set` as a functor, but I haven't been able to divine the right way to express that w/ the `remove_copy_if` algorithm.

**EDIT:** Fixed the logic error in `items()`. The actual code didn't have the problem, it was a transcription error.

**EDIT:** I have accepted a solution that doesn't use `std::set_difference` since it is more general and will work even if the `std::vector` isn't sorted. I chose to use the C++0x lambda expression syntax in my code. My final `items()` method looks like this:

```
std::vector<int> items() const {
    std::vector<int> good_items;
    good_items.reserve(all_items.size());
    std::remove_copy_if(all_items.begin(), all_items.end(),
                        std::back_inserter(good_items),
                        [&bad_items] (int const i) {
                            return bad_items.count(i) == 1;
                        });
}
```

On a vector of about 8 million items the above method runs in 3.1s. I bench marked the `std::set_difference` approach and it ran in approximately 2.1s. Thanks to everyone who supplied great answers.

Comment: Perhaps you could use std::set_difference? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_difference/

Comment: if you had no repeating objects you could use two sets and set operations for this. But I guess you need a vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your function is going to return a vector, you will have to make a new vector (i.e. copy elements) in any case. In which case, `std::remove_copy_if` is fine, but you should use it correctly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
std::vector<int> filter(const std::vector<int>& all, const std::set<int>& bad)
{
        std::vector<int> result;
        remove_copy_if(all.begin(), all.end(), back_inserter(result),
                  [&bad](int i){return bad.count(i)==1;});
        return result;
}

int main()
{
        std::vector<int> all_items = {4,5,2,3,4,8,7,56,4,2,2,2,3};
        std::set<int> bad_items = {2,8,4};
        std::vector<int> filtered_items = filter(all_items, bad_items);
        copy(filtered_items.begin(), filtered_items.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
        std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

To do this in C++98, I guess you could use `mem_fun_ref` and `bind1st` to turn set::count into a functor in-line, but there are issues with that (which resulted in deprecation of bind1st in C++0x) which means depending on your compiler, you might end up using std::tr1::bind anyway:

```
remove_copy_if(all.begin(), all.end(), back_inserter(result),
     bind(&std::set<int>::count, bad, std::tr1::placeholders::_1)); // or std::placeholders in C++0x
```

and in any case, an explicit function object would be more readable, I think:

```
struct IsMemberOf {
        const std::set<int>& bad;
        IsMemberOf(const std::set<int>& b) : bad(b) {}
        bool operator()(int i) const { return bad.count(i)==1;}
};
std::vector<int> filter(const std::vector<int>& all, const std::set<int>& bad)
{
        std::vector<int> result;
        remove_copy_if(all.begin(), all.end(), back_inserter(result), IsMemberOf(bad));
        return result;
}
```

Comment: +1... obviously, since this is about the same I had written myself and more complete!

Comment: Cubbi, thanks for the detailed answer. I've fixed the logic error--it was a transcription error and not present in the original code. I think you're right about readability. Can you explain your first solution a bit more? I'm not familiar with the syntax of the functor [&bad](int i)... is that creating a lambda expression of sorts?

Comment: @lrm: Yes, the first example uses C++0x lambda expressions. It builds a function object that captures "bad" by reference and exposes `bool operator()(int i) const` -- just like what you wrote originally, except using a reference rather than a pointer. It compiles with gcc 4.5+ (and, I imagine, MSVC10). The second bit uses C++TR1 generalized binders (available in std namespace of gcc 4.4+ in c++0x mode and also available as boost.bind for all C++98 compilers), and the third uses basic C++98.

Answer (score 8):

As jeffamaphone suggested, if you can sort any input vectors, you can use `std::set_difference` which is efficient and less code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> 
get_good_items( std::vector<int> const & all_items,
                std::set<int> const & bad_items )
{
    std::vector<int> good_items;

    // Assumes all_items is sorted.
    std::set_difference( all_items.begin(),
                         all_items.end(),
                         bad_items.begin(),
                         bad_items.end(),
                         std::back_inserter( good_items ) );

    return good_items;
}
```

Comment: @dribeas: I'm pretty sure that's what he meant when he said: "...if you can sort any input vectors..."

Comment: The vector is ordered. The data arrives to me in an ordered fashion and I insert it into the vector as such. I didn't use a set for this because I didn't want to add additional set comparator overhead for data that was already naturally ordered. Was that a mistake?

Comment: No, Lrm, that's fine, as long as the order in the vector is the same order they *would* be in if you'd used a set instead of the vector.

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of appearing archaic:

```
std::set<int> badItems;
std::vector<int> items;
std::vector<int> goodItems;
for ( std::vector<int>::iterator iter = items.begin();
      iter != items.end();
      ++iter)
{
   int& item = *iter;
   if ( badItems.find(item) == badItems.end() )
   {
      goodItems.push_back(item);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Craig. I'm trying to use the appropriate STL algorithm as it is item #43 of Meyer's effective STL.

Comment: @lrm: "appropriate STL algorithm" ... there are too much STL algorithms/etc for normal people to be able to memorize even half of them. I normally would write same as Craig. That is also K.I.S.S. compliant. Yet as the input vector is sorted, the code above is O(log(n)) while it can be done in O(n) by simply iterating the structures in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

`std::remove_copy_if` returns an iterator to the target collection.  In this case, it would return `good_items.end()` (or something similar).  `good_items` goes out of scope at the end of the method, so this would cause some memory errors.  You should return `good_items` or pass in a `new vector<int>` by reference and then `clear`, `resize`, and populate it.  This would get rid of the temporary variable.

I believe you have to define the custom functor because the method depends on the object `bad_items` which you couldn't specify without it getting hackey AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks Dave. This was an input error on my part. The actual code does return `good_items`. I've fixed it in the question.